# unable to login application, after hitting link of login page, it shows error please find above attachments. could you please check

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-mvc, dml

Not able to execute DML sql in the database: Not able to lookup the datasource:  java:/jboss/null_sti_common_ds[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51EhU.png)

enter image description here

```
21:59:23,914 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
21:59:23,914 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) started in 72019ms - Started 1248 of 1496 services (415 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
22:05:25,774 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-5) UT005023: Exception handling request to /phoenix/AppConfiguration.jsp: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.shipco.phoenix.core.shared.exception.DaoException: Not able to execute DML sql in the database: Not able to lookup the datasource:  java:/jboss/null_sti_common_ds
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:581)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:456)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:402)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:346)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.JsrWebSocketFilter.doFilter(JsrWebSocketFilter.java:130)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at com.cargomanager.util.jspformfilter.JSPFormsFilter.doFilter(JSPFormsFilter.java:40)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at com.shipco.phoenix.core.server.util.log.AccessFilter.doFilter(AccessFilter.java:40)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at com.shipco.phoenix.core.server.util.filter.cache.CacheControlFilter.doFilter(CacheControlFilter.java:75)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.jsp.JspFileHandler.handleRequest(JspFileHandler.java:32)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.shipco.phoenix.core.shared.exception.DaoException: Not able to execute DML sql in the database: Not able to lookup the datasource:  java:/jboss/null_sti_common_ds
    at org.apache.jsp.AppConfiguration_jsp._jspService(AppConfiguration_jsp.java:105)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: com.shipco.phoenix.core.shared.exception.DaoException: Not able to execute DML sql in the database: Not able to lookup the datasource:  java:/jboss/null_sti_common_ds
    at com.shipco.phoenix.core.server.util.session.listener.SessionDatabaseLogger.insertSessionData(SessionDatabaseLogger.java:137)
    at com.shipco.phoenix.core.server.util.session.listener.SessionDblistener.sessionCreated(SessionDblistener.java:124)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.sessionCreated(ApplicationListeners.java:304)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.SessionListenerBridge.sessionCreated(SessionListenerBridge.java:64)
    at io.undertow.server.session.SessionListeners.sessionCreated(SessionListeners.java:52)
    at io.undertow.server.session.InMemorySessionManager.createSession(InMemorySessionManager.java:185)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletContextImpl.getSession(ServletContextImpl.java:787)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.getSession(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:370)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.getSession(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:375)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.initialize(PageContextImpl.java:137)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalGetPageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:109)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.getPageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:60)
    at org.apache.jsp.AppConfiguration_jsp._jspService(AppConfiguration_jsp.java:83)
    ... 62 more
```

Comment: It's hard to help you without any further information. But as the stack trace says, the data source `java:/jboss/null_sti_common_ds` cannot be found. You should check if (and where) it is defined (usually in your `standalone.xml` or another config file of your WildFly) and referenced.

Comment: This data source "java:/jboss/null_sti_common_ds"   is not present in standalone.xml

Comment: OK, well I'm quite sure it should be. Somewhere else in your code or configuration, this data source is referenced. (Try a full text search.) Therefore it needs to be defined in your `standalone.xml`.

Comment: Thank you ahuemmer ,basically the point is i'm unable to  open my ui page , my project is running fine server is also working until i hit that ui link inti web, after hitting link error gives in my server "database error"  my team members got this issue but after few seconds application get open.

Comment: Humm, sorry, I cannot help you any more than what I wrote already. The `java:/jboss/null_sti_common_ds` is missing, that's what the error says. Perhaps your team members have it defined somewhere? Or, if they experience the same error but the application is running though, the error your posted may not really be the root of your problem.